# Using flutter_html to render a table with customRenders to apply Styling

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

I am trying to wrap my head around the flutter_html and flutter_html_all package and I spent the last few hours trying to render a table with some custom styling to no avail.

**What I want to do:**

Render a table from some HTML and apply styling to it.

- Add Custom Background if the table props have it
- Add Border Colours if the table props have it
- Add font-colours if the table props have it

The HTML looks something like this. I never know what types of tables I receive from my backend. Also excuse the color scheme its me just trying things out :)

```
[...]
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; background-color: #2DC26B; border-color: #f1c40f;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 32.87%;">Table</td>
<td style="width: 32.87%;">Test 1</td>
<td style="width: 32.8704%;">Test 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 32.87%;">Example 1</td>
<td style="width: 32.87%;">Value 1</td>
<td style="width: 32.8704%;">Value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 32.87%;">Example 2</td>
<td style="width: 32.87%;">Value 3</td>
<td style="width: 32.8704%;">Value 4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
[...]
```

I have tried to follow the docs provided [here](https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html#flutter_html_table)

However I couldn't replicate the example in said docs since it references `buildChildren` which I have no clue what it could be or where they get it from.

I am honestly lost to be frank and looking up various boards didn't help my confusion as there seems to be a difference between `flutter_html` and `flutter_html_all`

**I just want to access the attributes of my table element and modify the styling in there.**

If anyone could help me with just applying said style to my table I would be more than grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...

```
Widget toHtmlWidget(BuildContext context) {
return Html.fromDom(
  document: htmlparser.parse(this),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  onLinkTap: (String? url, Map<String, String> attributes, dom.Element? element) {
    url?.openUrl();
  },
  extensions: [
  //  TableHtmlExtension(),
  ],
  // customRender: {
  //   "table": (context, child) {
  //     return SingleChildScrollView(
  //       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  //       child: (context.tree as TableLayoutElement).toWidget(context),
  //     );
  //   }
  // },
  style: {
    "table": Style(
      backgroundColor: context.isDarkMode ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface : Colors.grey[100]
    ),
    "tr": Style(
      border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(
              color: context.isDarkMode
                  ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background
                  : Colors.white,
              width: 2
          ),
          bottom: BorderSide(
              color: context.isDarkMode
                  ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background
                  : Colors.white,
              width: 2
          ),
          left: BorderSide(
              color: context.isDarkMode
                  ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background
                  : Colors.white,
              width: 2
          ),
          right: BorderSide(
              color: context.isDarkMode
                  ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background
                  : Colors.white,
              width: 2
          )
      ),
    ),
    "th": Style(
      padding: HtmlPaddings.all(3),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    ),
    "td": Style(
      padding: HtmlPaddings.all(3),
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    ),
    "p": Style(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
    "h5": Style(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
    "span": Style(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
    "div": Style(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
  },
);
}
```